# Does jQuery modify the target element at all when creating an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For example:

```
$("myElement").click(function(){
alert("Clicked!");
};
```

Has the `#myElement` been modified, it's `onclick` attribute set, or did jQuery just set a listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `click()` function does **not** change any DOM attributes.

It adds a listener for that particular jQuery element.

The same goes for `.change(), .keyup(), ...` etcetera.

Comment: That's what I thought. Good ol' jQuery.

Comment: Just as a side note, you can see the events attached to a particular element by doing $('yourelement').data(). Under events you can see the events it's listening for.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery sets a listener if used `.click();`

Answer (score 0):

It does not modify the element.

> jQuery() — which can also be written as $() — searches through the DOM
>   for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new
>   jQuery object that references these elements

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jQuery 1.6.2 source:

```
$("myElement").click(...) calls: $("myElement").bind('click', ...) 
which then calls: jQuery.event.add(...) 
which ultimately does either elem.addEventListener(...) or elem.attachEvent(...)
```

So, we can say conclusively that it is not setting the `onclick` attribute (which is as we would expect since addEventListener is more extensible).

BUT, when I step through the .click() function, deep inside, an attribute **is** being added to the DOM object.  It's related to jQuery's data function and it in this piece of code in jQuery's data function which is called from `event.add(...)`.  It looks like it's some sort of guid identifier that jQuery uses to keep track of which object is which without keeping a DOM reference (which can lead to memory leaks).  The code that adds that attribute is here:

```
   if ( !id ) {
        // Only DOM nodes need a new unique ID for each element since their data
        // ends up in the global cache
        if ( isNode ) {
            elem[ jQuery.expando ] = id = ++jQuery.uuid;
        } else {
            id = jQuery.expando;
        }
    }
```

So, in conclusion, jQuery is not touched the `.onclick` attribute, but it is setting at least one other attribute on the DOM object when setting the first event handler.

Comment: why would you expect it to set an attribute?!

Comment: You misunderstood my meaning (which was poorly written and I have now changed).  I was **not** expecting it to set the onclick attribute.  But, as it turns out, it does set a different attribute on the DOM object.